# Countinue the animation when the element has been replaced with another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have an element, which has a CSS animation.

After 3 seconds, the Javascript replace the element with another new element (but same `div` element).

I want the new element to continue the rest unfinished part of the animation but not restart the animation.

Is it possible to fulfill it?

```js
function replaceDIV(){
    var elm = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    var new_elm = document.createElement("div");
    new_elm.innerHTML = "New Element";
    new_elm.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    elm.parentNode.replaceChild(new_elm,elm);
}
setTimeout(function(){
    replaceDIV();
}, 3000);
```

```css
div {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 8s linear forwards;
    animation: mymove 8s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 500px;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 500px;}
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: red;">Original Element</div>
```

How can I continue the rest unfinished CSS animation after the DIV has changed into a new DIV?

Is it possible to fulfill it with only CSS? Or it must use Javascript?

Comment: instead of replacing the element, couldn't you just update the element text and background color ?

Comment: My first thought would be; don't animate the div that will be removed. Animate a container element.

Comment: you are already using JS in all the cases, so the JS question is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Animating the container div and then swapping out the inner div will get you to the solution that you want.

The problem is that when you're swapping out the same dom element it effectively resets the CSS animation to the beginning -- but if you're animating the container and swapping out the inner element then nothing will be interrupted.

In the below snippet I:

- Created`.container-div`
- Updated CSS applied to that container div
- Updated index of `var elm` declaration

```js
function replaceDIV(){
    var elm = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];
    var new_elm = document.createElement("div");
    new_elm.innerHTML = "New Element";
    new_elm.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    elm.parentNode.replaceChild(new_elm,elm);
}
setTimeout(function(){
    replaceDIV();
}, 3000);
```

```css
.container-div {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 8s linear forwards;
    animation: mymove 8s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 500px;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 500px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container-div"><div style="background-color: red;">Original Element</div></div>
```